# Syntax error converting datetime from character string 4

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

Getting this code error when executing the following code.. Help would be appreciated

```
DECLARE @Last_Timestamp DATETIME, 
        @New_Timestamp  DATETIME 

SELECT DISTINCT Rtrim(of_displayname) + ' (' 
                + Rtrim(ro_officer) + ')', 
                CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(11), ro_shift_start, 106), 106), 
                Rtrim(ac_name) + ' (' + Rtrim(ac_pin) + ')', 
                ro_officer 
FROM   roster WITH(nolock), 
       template WITH(nolock), 
       activity WITH(nolock), 
       officer WITH(nolock) 
WHERE  ro_status = 'INFO' 
       AND ro_activity IN ( 'LEAVE', 'SAL LEAVE' ) 
       AND ro_timestamp > @Last_Timestamp 
       AND ro_timestamp <= @New_Timestamp 
       AND ro_shift_start > Getdate() 
       AND ac_pin = to_activity 
       AND to_pin = ro_officer 
       AND Unicode(to_type) = Unicode('M') 
       AND ro_officer = of_pin 
       --AND (Of_Payroll_No    IN ('w','s')   
       AND ac_product_code IN ( '01', '09' ) /* Corporate Only */ /* W & S */ 
UNION 
SELECT [officer], 
       [activity], 
       [status], 
       [comment] 
FROM   production.rolecall.[dbo].[holidayrequest] 
ORDER  BY Rtrim(of_displayname) + ' (' 
          + Rtrim(ro_officer) + ')',RTRIM(Of_Displayname)  + ' (' + RTRIM(Ro_Officer) + ')',CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(11), RO_Shift_Start,106),106)
```

Comment: Please add the errmessage and the ddl(database definition).

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Syntax error converting datetime from character string.

Comment: Have you tried checking what the contents of `ro_shift_start` are, to see if they match the expected format? Although note that since `@Last_Timestamp` and `@New_Timestamp` are both `null`, we shouldn't expect any rows in the top grid here...

Comment: By looking at your code your are converting ro_shift_start to char and then again converting to datetime, cant you just use ro_shift_start instead of CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(11), ro_shift_start, 106)?

Comment: @KiranHegde I'm guessing that is intended as "get the date without the time" - in which case there are other approaches that can be used, but equally: the one shown *should be fine* (but inefficient); in which case, I strongly suspect that the real problem is the `UNION`

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks marc , the union does seem to be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 places where you are doing date conversions here:

- `CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(11), ro_shift_start, 106), 106)`
- `CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(11), RO_Shift_Start,106),106)`
- the `UINON`

The first two look like you are actually trying to get the day without the time. If so: *get the day without the time*; there are various ways of doing this, but in recent versions of sql server, casting it to a `date` would work fine:

```
select cast(columnname as date) as [columnname]
```

or if you really need it as `datetime`:

```
 select cast(cast(columnname as date) as datetime) as [columnname]
```

On other database versions you can use the sneeky "cast it as a float" approach:

```
select cast(floor(cast(columnname as float)) as datetime) as [columnname]
```

The `UNION` is more interesting; it looks like these are very different shapes - in which case: *why are you unioning them*? I very much doubt that `[activity]` is a `datetime`, yet that is the column it will become part of. It is entirely possible that this error is coming from trying to convert `[activity]` to a `datetime`.